# Search all sources "filter by path" in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The "search all sources" input box in the Chrome (54.0.2840.71) developer tools has some placeholder text that reads "Search all sources (use "file:" to filter by path).

I've been hoping a path/folder filter would be added for a while, as with large apps it can take a while to search all the source code.

I've tried a few things to try and get the filter by path to work, but haven't been able to get it to work. Is there any documentation for this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a feeling this is a bug, but you need to put the search term before the filter - it doesn't work if you put it after:

[image]

You can also search for a directory:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is kind of unintuitive. It would at least be nice to make the place holder text a little more specific.